# Rails is sending params that i didn't make

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a create chat room page.

If the user enter data and press create button it calls this jquery function.

```
$(".create_room_btn").click(function(){
            var token = $("#authenticity_token").val();
            var appointmentName = $("#appointmentName").val();
            var date = $("#Date").val();
            var start_time = $("#start_time").val();
            var end_time = $("#end_time").val();
            var roomType = $("#roomType").val();
            var numberOfParticipants = $("#numberOfParticipants").val();
            var appointmentDescription = $("#appointmentDescription").val();
            var roomValue = '"roomvalue": {';
            //roomValue += '"token": "' + token + '",';
            roomValue += '"appointmentName": "' + appointmentName + '",';
            roomValue += '"Date": "' + date+ '",';
            roomValue += '"start_time": "' + start_time + '",';
            roomValue += '"end_time": "' + end_time + '",';
            roomValue += '"roomType": "' + roomType + '",';
            roomValue += '"numberOfParticipants": "' + numberOfParticipants + '",';
            roomValue += '"appointmentDescription": "' + appointmentDescription + '"';
            roomValue += '}';


            var attendeeList = '"attenddeelist": [';
            $("#invited_table tr").find('td').each(function(a,b){
                if(b.cellIndex==0){
                    attendeeList += '{ "id": "' + b.innerHTML+'"';
                }else if(b.cellIndex==1){
                    attendeeList += ',"firstname": "' + b.innerHTML+'"';
                }else if(b.cellIndex==2){
                    attendeeList += ',"lastname": "' + b.innerHTML+'"';
                }else if(b.cellIndex==3){
                    attendeeList += ',"email": "' + b.innerHTML+'"},';
                }
                //console.log(b.innerHTML);
            })
            // delete the last "," to make a json format
            attendeeList = attendeeList.substring(0,attendeeList.lastIndexOf(","));
            attendeeList += ']';

            //var params = '{' + '"authenticity_token":"'+token+"","+ roomValue + ',' + attendeeList + '}';

            var params = "{"+roomValue + "," + attendeeList + "}";
            //console.log(params);


            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
                url : "/room/createroom",
                dataType : "json",
                data :  params,
                success : function() {
                    return false;
                },
                error: function(){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

in here, gets all the data, and made on json format, send it to the controller.

but If i check the params in there, it is sending "room" that i didn't make.

```
Parameters: {"roomvalue"=>{"appointmentName"=>"title", "Date"=>"date", "start_time"=>"start", "end_time"=>"end", "roo
mType"=>"1", "numberOfParticipants"=>"max", "appointmentDescription"=>"des"}, "attenddeelist"=>[{"id"=>"22", "firstname
"=>"Michimasa", "lastname"=>"Ueematsu", "email"=>"Michimasa.Uematsu@access-company.com"}, {"id"=>"16", "firstname"=>"Ha
eseok", "lastname"=>"Maeng", "email"=>"Haeseok.Maeng@access-company.com"}, {"id"=>"0", "firstname"=>"fist", "lastname"=
>"las", "email"=>"email"}], "room"=>{"roomvalue"=>{"appointmentName"=>"title", "Date"=>"date", "start_time"=>"start", "
end_time"=>"end", "roomType"=>"1", "numberOfParticipants"=>"max", "appointmentDescription"=>"des"}, "attenddeelist"=>[{
"id"=>"22", "firstname"=>"Michimasa", "lastname"=>"Ueematsu", "email"=>"Michimasa.Uematsu@access-company.com"}, {"id"=>
"16", "firstname"=>"Haeseok", "lastname"=>"Maeng", "email"=>"Haeseok.Maeng@access-company.com"}, {"id"=>"0", "firstname
"=>"fist", "lastname"=>"las", "email"=>"email"}]}}
```

Any good reason and solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send _all_ of those params each time your user hits "send"? It seems like hugely inefficient to me? I could try and refactor your code if you want?

Comment: @Rich Peck Thank you, but after send, it redirects to another page, so it won't be a problem :)

Comment: Okay, if you feel it's best!

Comment: the problem is probably elsewhere in your code, there's no reason why Rails should add an object to the params hash out of thin air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen something similar, where the params are cloned under a node named the same as my controller action, in your case it looks to be under a node named after your controller - my guess is something weird happens when rails parses the incoming json into the params ruby hash

unrelated to this, is there a reason you are building up json as a string? shouldn't the following work:

```
var attendeeList = [];

$("#invited_table tr").each(function (index, element) {
  var attendee = {};

  element.find('td').each(function (a, b) {
    if(b.cellIndex==0){
      attendee['id'] = b.innerHTML;
    }else if(b.cellIndex==1){
      attendee['firstname'] = b.innerHTML;
    }else if(b.cellIndex==2){
      attendee['lastname'] = b.innerHTML;
    }else if(b.cellIndex==3){
      attendee['email'] = b.innerHTML;
    }
  });

  attendeeList.push(attendee);
});

var params = {
  roomvalue: {
    appointmentName: $("#appointmentName").val(),
    "Date": $("#Date").val(),
    start_time: $("#start_time").val(),
    end_time: $("#end_time").val(),
    roomType: $("#roomType").val(),
    numberOfParticipants: $("#numberOfParticipants").val(),
    appointmentDescription: $("#appointmentDescription").val(),
    attendeelist: attendeeList
  }
};   

// make ajax call ...
```

Also consider using a naming convention if possible, right now you have the following:

- lower with underscore ('end_time', 'start_time')
- camel
- Pascal ('Date')
- all lower with no underscores ('roomvalue', 'attendeelist')

its going to lead to confusion, I would pick one style - doesn't matter which.

> Typically in ruby you use lower_case_with_under_score for variables and PascalCase for class names. Javascript is usually camelCase.